# A book from the 90s about a girl living in a world about to be destroyed

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

It was a story about a girl who lived in a citadel and the world was about to be destroyed and she met a boy named Delos (I believe) but I don't remember her name. Not much to go on but I remember I loved this book when I was young and I have tried everything I can think of to look it up...

Comment: What do you mean by about to be destroyed? (natural) apocalypse of some sort? Sun dying? Implosion/Explosion? Human war (nuclear or otherwise)? Ice age?

Comment: Cleared away to make room for an interstellar bypass?

Comment: I vaguely remember Z for Zachariah is like this,  but that was a valley not a citadel, and after the end not before.  Anything you can add might help.

Comment: I think it was like earthquakes or some sort of natural disaster but the ruling class had fore-knowledge of impending disaster and were prepared with spaceships. Delos was a common boy and wasn't allowed to be around her but they bonded anyway and he saves her life. I hate myself right now for not being able to remember more

Answer (score 5):

How about Skyborn by Marcia Krutchen?

[image]

From [PaperBack Swap](http://www.paperbackswap.com/Skyborn-Marcia-H-Kruchten/book/059040279X/):

> Clea is the grand-daughter of the King of Atlantic, but she is bored
>   by her confortable life in the Citadel. Then a mysterious stranger
>   arrives at the palace. Who is Delos, and why has he come? Is he
>   connected with the plot against her grandfather? And what does the
>   King mean when he says they are both Skyborn? In her search for the
>   answers, Clea is caught up in a dangerously exciting adventure.